# JQuery validation - resetting error state from javascript

Tags: jquery-validate

I'm trying to use JQuery Validation to validate a form.

I have one field that can be empty, but if non-empty must have digits.  JQuery validation handles that fine by setting "class='digits'".  My problem is that I have a button that uses javascript to clear the field.

If I type a non-digit into the field, I have a "Please enter only digits" error displayed.  If I click the button, the field is cleared, but the "Please enter only digits" error is still displayed. This is incorrect, because for the field to be empty is not an error.

I'm clearing the field with:

```
jQuery('#mybutton').click(function()
{
    jQuery('#myfield').val('');
});
```

This is working.

I figured I could re-run the validation with:

```
jQuery('#mybutton').click(function()
{
    jQuery('#myfield').val('');
    jQuery('#myfield').validate();
});
```

There is a validate() method defined on the jQuery object, but calling it does not cause the error message to disappear.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are not supposed to call `.validate()` from within a click handler.  It's simply the initialization method of the plugin.  The click handler is automatic after that.

Answer (score 0):

the jquery validate provides a reset function for this.

```
resetForm();
```

Comment: I don't want to reset all the fields on the form, I just want to change the one, and then re-run the validation.